# jQuery click function to get data count and apply to span count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Its late so likely something im totally missing and being stupid but any ideas why its not updating the data value on clicked element and the count inside the span?

```js
// simple like count function for demo
$('.action-like').on('click tap', function() {
  var currentCount = $(this).data('like-count');
  var newCount = currentCount + 1;
  $(this).data('like-count', newCount);
  $(this).find('.count').html(newCount);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn--secondary action-like" data-like-count="1">Like</a> <span class="small"><span class="count">1</span> person likes this</span>
</p>

<p><a href="#" class="btn btn--primary action-like" data-like-count="5">Like</a> <span class="small">You and <span class="count">5</span> other people like this</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget marking an answer &/ upvote if any of them are sufficient.

Comment: I know, was not letting me before as has to be a certain / minimum amount of minutes before i can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no `.count` inside the `a` link. You could solve it by traversing to the parent and then do your `find`.

Like so:

```
$('.action-like').on('click tap', function() {
  var currentCount = $(this).data('like-count');
  var newCount = currentCount + 1;
  $(this).data('like-count', newCount);
  $(this).parent().find('.count').html(newCount);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).parent().find('.count').html(newCount);
```

The key is that your `this` is referencing to the `a` which is sibiling of `.count`.